# Google Maps v2 Autorization failed

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, permissions, maps

This error appears. Sorry for that question, but I can't investigate it.

```
12-29 12:03:59.705: E/Google Maps Android API(15395): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
12-29 12:03:59.720: E/Google Maps Android API(15395): In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
Google Maps Android API: Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: com.example.testmaps, API Key: XXX, Certificate Fingerprint: ZZZ
Google Maps Android API: Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
Google Maps Android API: Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

This is code of Manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <permission
        android:name="package.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="package.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />

    </application>
```

I checked API KEY on console and enabled Google Maps Android API v2. But all the monkey job.
Also I tried to use signed application but now all SHA1 keys which sended on server are correct.

this log maybee needed:

```
12-29 14:41:30.465: I/Google Maps Android API(27463): Google Play services client version: 5084000
12-29 14:41:30.465: I/Google Maps Android API(27463): Google Play services package version: 6599038
```

Checked on Samsung S4

**Solution:**
Seems it is need to use
import com.google.android.gms
instead of 
import com.google.android.m4b
for maps

Comment: your developing the code in Eclipse/Android Studio.

Comment: If your working with Eclipse try to import the Library project,located at: ANDROID-SDK-DIRECTORY/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject

Comment: be sure to sign the app with your *release* key and put your *release* key in the developer console, if you try to run on the emulator or on the phone without exporting and signing your app, you are using your *debug* key

Comment: have you imported the Library project into your workspace.The project which you are developing and the Library project should be in the same working directory.

Comment: yes. I imported google_play_services on my project. target 21.

Comment: your able to see the green color right mark in,click on project -->Alt+Enter-->Android see there your library project is correctly configured.

Comment: is your SDK is up-to-date.If not once you try to install under Extras --> Google Play Services

Comment: I tried to sign my application with release key, but problem exists after that.

Comment: your are checking the app in physical device/Emulator.

Comment: google_maps-sdk-m4b_lib and google_play_services__lib plaged in to project correctly. Eclipse has no error. I can buid my app. But problem exists yet.

Comment: If you are sure that the API key is right, and this error still comes up Logcat, then try this:

1)Uninstall app from device.
2)Clean the project
3)And run on device again

Comment: I tried to clean project before build and each time uninstall app on build.

Comment: this is something else.

Comment: Activate the Google Maps Android API v2 service in the Google API's console. Also, after making changes do a full reinstall of the app on the device/emulator.

Comment: problem still exists

Comment: Google Maps Android API v2 and other services related with maps activated on console.

Comment: try to check your sha-1 key;package and try to generate the api key

Comment: when error is appears SHA1 key and key on server are same. Same with API Key. SHA1;package is correct.

Comment: try to place single api key,remove backup meta-tag

Comment: with removed backup meta-tag authorization filed still appears..

Comment: I've had the same issue, when started app from another ps and SHA1 key was not correct (but i dont know why)